# Objective - C how do I change the color of UINavigationItem

Tags: objective-c, xcode

How do I change the colour of the UINavigationItem from black to white?

[image]

I have tried the following in my LHAppDelegate.m:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:UIColorFromRGB(0xFFFFFF)];


[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

changes the whole bar to green, I am trying to change the colour of the black text 'Update Tasks'

[image]

Comment: Hope, you're adding this code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`? Otherwise, `viewWillAppear` of your view controller should be the best location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a solid color for your navigation bar in **iOS 6** similar to iOS 7 use this:

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

---

in **iOS 7** use the `barTintColor` like this:

```
navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

or

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

---

### Edit 1

To update the text color, use below.

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName : [UIColor whiteColor]}];
```

Comment: `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];` changes the colour of the whole navigation Bar, I am looking to change just the colour of the text inside the navigation Bar, the 'Update Tasks' text.